# Como copiar un texto desde un hidden en firefox

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox

el script es el siguiente:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".cpyBtn").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetPassword","Credential")',
            type: "get",
            data: {
                idCredential: @Model.ID
            },
            traditional: true,
            cache: false,
            success: function (process) {
                $("#passDecrypted-" + @Model.ID).val(process);
                let copyFrom = document.createElement("textarea");
                document.body.appendChild(copyFrom);
                copyFrom.textContent = $("#passDecrypted-" + @Model.ID).val();
                copyFrom.select();
                document.execCommand("copy");
                copyFrom.remove();
                console.log($("#passDecrypted-" + @Model.ID).val());
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

mirandolo con la herramienta de desarrollo de firefox en consola cuando pulso sobre el icono me salta el siguiente mensaje:

document.execCommand('cut'/'copy') ha sido denegado porque no ha sido llamado desde dentro de un manejador de eventos generado por el usuario de ejecución breve.

Answer (score 1):

Como se indica en el error `document.execCommand('cut'/'copy')` sólo está permitido usarlo (sin permisos) en manejadores de eventos de corta duración generados por el usuario (por ejemplo, un click). En tu caso (aunque la llamada a ajax esté englobada en un click el contexto no es el mismo por lo que no te va a dejar). Más [info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard)

Existe la opción de dar [permisos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/permissions) al navegador para permitir esto pero no es una solución global.

En esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41361081/clipboard-copy-does-not-work-in-jquery-ajax-success-method) de SO proponen varias soluciones. Una de ellas es lanzar la llamada ajax en vez de en el `click` en el `mouseenter` (guardando el valor en un input) y luego cuando se hace el `click` copiar en el portapapeles. Evidentemente esto no es muy eficiente ya que hará una llamada cada vez que el usuario ponga el ratón encima del botón... así que habría que valorar si merece la pena.

Te dejo este ejemplo modificado de una de las respuestas:

```js
$('.list').on('click', function() {  
   let copyFrom = document.createElement("textarea");
    document.body.appendChild(copyFrom);
    //Obtenemos el valor del hidden
    copyFrom.textContent = $("#hidClip").val();
    copyFrom.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    copyFrom.remove();  
});

$('.list').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $.get("http://echo.jsontest.com/uid/12345/value/nuno_bettencourt", function(data) {
        var json = {
            json: JSON.stringify(data),
            delay: 1
        };
        //Guardamos en el hidden el JSON obtenido (o lo que interese de la respuesta)
        $("#hidClip").val(JSON.stringify(data)); 
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="list" value="Copiar en el portapapeles"></input>
<input type="text" placeholder="¡Pégame el texto!"/>
<input type="hidden" id="hidClip"/>
```